# How to construct this regular expression?

Tags: regex, preg-match

How to ignore abc and def,01 in below expression using regex. I tried ignore me it doesn’t work.

> Abc-def-smdp-01

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Then come back and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

One way to go is to split the original string into prefix, portion of interest, and suffix, removing the unwanted charcters in the affixes thereafter:

```
$raw = "abc-def-smdp-01";

preg_match ( "/^(.*)(-smdp-)(.*)$/", $raw, $matches );    // separate original string into prefix, trunk, suffix  
$matches[1] = preg_replace ( "/[^-]/", "", $matches[1] ); // non-'-' characters deleted in prefix
$matches[3] = preg_replace ( "/[^-]/", "", $matches[3] ); // non-'-' characters deleted in suffixfix
$result = $matches[1].$matches[2].$matches[3]; // composing target string

echo $result;
```

Online demo available [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/269140c6040f5f56b66da7c0c43edf8add166b07).

***NB***

Problems similar to this one can be tackled easily with some knowledge of the php function library whose [doc within the online php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/funcref.php) comes with exakt syntax, example code, and user comments.

In this case, look up:

- [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)
- [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

Of course, finding suitable candidates for the intended functionality assumes at least a perfunctory grasp  of the available facilities which makes the 15 minutes of browsing the [hierarchical index](http://php.net/manual/en/funcref.php) a judicious investment of time

Comment: can you tell me this using Regex not in PHP

Comment: What's your programming environment? And why do you  tag your question with `preg_match` if it's not php?

Comment: Clarifying my previous comment: Pure regexen are used to _match text patterns_ - however, you also want to _modify_ the finds which requires knowledge of what programming environment is being used.

Answer (score 0):

I would use this pattern:

```
preg_match("/\w+\-\w+\-(\w+)\-\d+/", "Abc-def-smdp-01", $output);
Echo $output[1];
```

http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/ftB

EDIT: or do you need the dashes?
In that case you need to use this pattern:`"/\w+(\-)\w+(\-)(\w+)(\-)\d+/"`
And then output it as:
`echo $output[1].$output[2].$output[3].$output[4];`
or loop it and build a string with `.=`